# Javascript: How to add values to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

First of all I currently work in Google Sheets with Javascript to create a macro.

For my project I want to use a **while loop to add values to an array.** I used the `Array.push(Variable);` command. Before adding the values to the array I saved the value in a variable.

I checked if the values are stored correctly in the variable by writing these values in different cells in a google sheet. So this can't be the source of the mistake.
I also tried writing the values stored in the array to different cells in the google sheet but the Output is `"undefined"`.

For my understanding the mistake is in **adding the values to the array.** Below you can see some code.

```js
var row = 2;
var col = 1;

var rowCheck = 2;
var colCheck = 3;

var isSelected = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(rowCheck, colCheck).getValue();

var AddToArray;

//Add all PID´s to an array
while (i < HideValues.lenght + 1) {
  if (isSelected == 0) {
    AddToArray = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, col).getValue();
    HideValues.push(AddToArray);           //mistake in this line?                                
    //spreadsheet.getRange('\'Visualization\'!K' + i).setValue(AddToArray);
    i++;
    row++;
    rowCheck++;
  } else {
    //spreadsheet.getRange('\'Visualization\'!K' + i).setValue(AddToArray);
    i++;
    row++;
    rowCheck++;
  }
}
```

Comment: `HideValues.lenght` -> `HideValues.length`

Comment: check `AddToArray` before push that you  got value in `AddToArray` or not

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I checke ```AddToArray``` and everything works fine there. The value changes correctly in each run of the while-loop. It just seems like the values don't get added to the array for some reason.

Comment: see as first comment `lenght` should be `length`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra  thanks, I already changed it. It solved to problem. The values are now stored in the array.

Answer (score 0):

`HideValues.lenght` -> `HideValues.length`